# Applying ANOVAs to overlapping data subsets

Tags: anova

Assume I have an experimental design involving two factors, each of which has three levels:

Factor 1:

- level 1
- level 2
- level 3

Factor 2:

- level a
- level b
- level c

However, during the experiment I did not use every possible combination of the factor levels. More precisely, I skipped the combination of (Factor 1 == level 1) and (Factor 2 == level a), as shown in the following table:

```
                       Factor 1
                   1     2     3
                  -------------------
            a   |  no    yes   yes  
                |  
Factor 2    b   |  yes   yes   yes 
                |
            c   |  yes   yes   yes
```

Where 'yes' means that data is available for this combination of factors.

Now I want to use an ANOVA to test whether one of the factors has a significant influence on the results. In addition, I want to learn about possible interaction effects. However, since I do not have a complete factorial design (one factor combination is missing), I cannot apply an ANOVA to the entire dataset at once. Instead I thought I would split up the dataset into two overlapping subsets like so:

Subset 1:

```
                    Factor 1
                    2     3
                -------------------
            a   |   yes   yes  
                |  
Factor 2    b   |   yes   yes   
                |
            c   |   yes   yes
```

Subset 2:

```
                       Factor 1
                   1     2     3
                  -------------------
Factor 2    b   |  yes   yes   yes 
                |
            c   |  yes   yes   yes
```

Each of these subsets is a complete factorial dataset, i.e. no factor combination is missing. Next, I analyse these datasets separately from each other by means of an ANOVA.

Is it correct to do it like this, especially considering that the subsets overlap?

---

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that I did some research on this topic, but the only thing I could find was this question on ResearchGate:

[ResearchGate: Incomplete factorial designs](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_incomplete_factorial_designs_be_statistically_analyzed)

The top answer (by Jochen Wilhem) suggests using "*A one-way Anova with a factor containg all the possible level-combinations of the original factors*".

However, by doing so, I would not be able to analyse interactions between the factors, which is vital for me.